# Mesh partially deforms while posing

Tags: mesh, armature

So yeah, here's the deal. I decided to combine two models, joined both armatures properly, yadda yadda yadda - but the second model's legs (I joined them around the first armature) just go haywire. Pic 1 - thigh is 90 degrees, knee is 90. Pic 2 - pelvis is also moved. Basically, the legs PARTIALLY don't react to the armature. The funnier thing is that I tried to paint the weights and they still didn't completely move the legs where they belong. I also tried to copy properties from the source model for the legs - still no result. What can I do?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

> joined both armatures properly, yadda yadda yadda

Well... From the looks of it, "properly" isn't the word if they were functional before you joined them.

Check the weight in that area, make sure they are correctly assigned. That means:

- In weight pain mode, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> that area and see the list of assigned weights. Make sure each of these weight make sense and are needed.
- Each vertex must be assigned at least once somewhere, and the total of weight per vertex must not exceed 1.0. You can check that by selecting a vertex in edit mode and look at the wieghts list in the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "Properly" indeed isn't the word at the end of the day. I've checked the vertex groups, they're the same between the models, even copying them from source to target didn't do the trick. This time I manually assigned the whole leg to the 'thigh' bone and got this (link below). So there's **some** progress but still not enough. Do you have any ideas?

https://sun9-52.userapi.com/impg/Oz6r2H1dS-ji5GcmGTg11tVDsZmhGSpBUzs2zw/EdPVEaDe09o.jpg?size=1920x1080&quality=96&sign=d4284031c4a7e426cc7e0fec208d22ed&type=album

Comment: it's not just a matter of assigning vertex, it's also making sure you don't assign them "too much" so to speak. Also make sure the bones and vertex groups names are the same, that's how they are linked.

Comment: I copied all the properties from the original legs to the copied ones, including vertex group and everything the ctrl+C menu could offer me. The legs still didn't move as much as I wanted them. The thing is, I tried to add more weight on 'ctr' bones and it moved the leg closer to where it belongs - but still not 100%.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you copied stuff from whatever. `The thing is, I tried to add more weight on 'ctr' bones and it moved the leg closer to where it belongs - but still not 100%`
This highly suggests the weights are not good and you have to check them as I described. Have you done that yet?